# Views Slideshow - showing only one slide

Tags: views, javascript

I've the content type, from which I want to take one field: title and present it as a block somewhere on the page. Sounds rather easy, but maybe my brain has melted already.

I installed Views Slideshow, created new view and it seems to work. To some degree, because it's only showing me one slide (title) and when it's fading, nothing new appears. When I choose the format for example to unformatted list, it shows all the titles it should, but in slideshow format it just doesn't work. What I'm missing here?

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

Comment: Instead of using Photobucket, please add your screenshots directly to your posts using the image button.  This will help future users of the site because it ensures that your post will always have your picture as long as this site is live.

Comment: This screenshot isn't really enough evidence to know what is causing your issue. Have you only tested the slideshow in the Views preview area or have you tested it by placing the Views block on a page in your site? If you inspect the HTML, are all the titles being rendered in HTML as expected, or is only one title rendered in HTML? Are there any javascript or PHP errors on your site?

Comment: Thanks for answering. It doesn't work both on preview and in block - when places in block, I see the code working fine with correct titles and cycling is working too. I don't see any errors in logs regarding views slideshow - what information would be needed beside screenshot?

Comment: ok, I realized that display:none; isn't changing to display:block; when it should. Only first slide is changing the value, and the rest of slides are still on "none". How to fix that?

Comment: I guess no one knows the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The possible directions you can look into :

1. You need to install the jQuery cycle plugin. Create a directory in sites/all/libraries called jquery.cycle, and then copy jquery.cycle.all.min.js or jquery.cycle.all.js into it. You can find the plugin at http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle.
2. In views slide show settings check for the 'Timer delay' in 'View Transition Advanced Options'.

   Also, check for the other options in views slide show settings.
3. In the views settings, you are only showing published contents for a particular type of content. Make sure you have more than one such content. (Based on your screen shot)
4. Considering you have enabled 'Views Slideshow: Cycle' module

(Answer is based on trial to regenerate the issue in D7, 7.22)

Hope it helps